# Generic abstract base class from Generic Interface

Tags: c#-4.0, generics, inheritance, interface, abstract-class

I'm trying to understand what hierarchy would be the best for inheritance described as following. So far I have had as following:

```
public interface IManager<T> where T : ISomeObject
{
    bool Add(T o);
    bool Remove(T o);
    bool Update(T o);
}
```

But then I wanted each derived classes to have a parameterised constructor. So I went:

```
public abstract class Manager<T> : IManager<T> where T : ISomeObject
{
    protected readonly INeededObject obj;

    protected Manager(INeededObject o)
    {
         obj = o;
    }
}
```

Any ideas on how should I go about this design issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be a bit of late night 'wisdom rush' (which can be wrong again). But modified my interface to be a non-generic one as followed:

```
public interface IManager
{
    bool Add(ISomeObject o);
    bool Remove(ISomeObject o);
    bool Update(ISomeObject o);
}
```

And my abstract class looks like following:

```
public abstract class Manager<T> : IManager<T> where T : ISomeObject
{
    protected readonly INeededObject obj;

    protected Manager(INeededObject o)
    {
         obj = o;
    }

    public abstract bool Add(T o);
    bool IManager.Add(ISomeObject obj)
    {
        return this.Add( (T) obj );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You're almost there. You can use generic type parameters in your base class as well.

```
public abstract class Manager<T> : IManager<T> where T : ISomeObject
{
    protected readonly T obj;

    protected Manager(T o)
    {
         obj = o;
    }
}
```

You can use parameterized types too, like

```
protected Manager(IList<T> o)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: I dont know but having to define what `T` both in `interface` and `abstract class` feels a bit weird and wrong.

Comment: @Kunal you're not 'defining' `T` in two places. `T` is just a parameter name - kind of like a function parameter. You can actually give `T` any name you want in both places, e.g. `class Manager<Foo>`. `T` is just a convention.

Comment: Yes I understand the generics usage, however I still think having to redundantly specify what type is `T`, both in `interface` and `abstract class`, is not right somewhere along OOD lines. I agree that yours is one way to do parameterised constructor, but my edit is what I was looking for (unless there's a  flaw).

Comment: Yep, that designed in my edit worked fine for me. 
@p.s.w.g - Thanks for your valuable opinion.